# MIPS loat float without li.s

Tags: floating-point, mips

I am trying to load a floating point integer in MIPS without a pseudocode instruction such as li.s does anyone know how I would go about doing that for an example like 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and this is what I found:

In Mars you can't use li.s because it's a pseudonot implemented. In PCSPIM it's implemented, something like

```
li.s $f2, 9.0
```

In PCSPIM will be traduced into

```
lui $1, 16656
mtc1 $1, $f2
```

So, if you want to do li.s but you don't want to call li.s you can always load your program into PCSPIM (with li.s) and see what changes in your code and then substitute you code for those changes.

But be careful, in PCSPIM you can't

```
lui $1, 16656
mtc1 $1, $f2
```

It's gonna trow a nice error to you.

It's cheap and chessy, I know, but it do the trick...